# Android.mk add binary into /system/bin

Tags: makefile, android-source, android.mk

I have a binary, with Android.mk as below.

```
include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE := binary_test
LOCAL_LDLIBS := libs
LOCAL_CFLAGS := -O3 -UNDEBUG

LOCAL_C_INCLUDES += tools/
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := main.c

include $(BUILD_EXECUTABLE)
```

And I want to add the binary_test into android /system/bin how this can be done?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android use [PRODUCT_PACKAGES](https://source.android.com/setup/develop/new-device#prod-def) to include all modules to be installed.

Add the following lines to your product makefiles.

```
PRODUCT_PACKAGES += binary_test
```